# Why does my Python cubic regression not fit the model?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, regression

I'm trying to plot a regression using a cubic model, but whenever I run it I get a regression that looks like the below image. I calculated my regression coefficients using matrices, and the `x4` and `y` values are just arrays of 500 numbers.

My regression attempt:

[image]

```
x4 = np.array(x4)

x4_cubed = x4 * x4 * x4
x4_squared = x4 * x4

x_mat_x4 = np.vstack((np.ones(len(x4)), x4, x4_squared, x4_cubed)).T

x_mat_x4[0:5,]
beta_hat_x4 = np.linalg.inv(x_mat_x4.T.dot(x_mat_x4)).dot(x_mat_x4.T).dot(y)

y_line_x4 = beta_hat_x4[0] + x4 * beta_hat_x4[1] + x4_squared * beta_hat_x4[2] + x4_cubed * beta_hat_x4[3]

plt.scatter(x4, y, c='yellow')

plt.plot(x4, y_line_x4, c='purple', label='Regression Fit')

plt.xlabel('X4 Values')
plt.ylabel('Y Values')
plt.title('Y Values vs X4 Predictor Values')
plt.show()
```

How do I get the regression to fit the model, instead of having the weird shape it has now?

I tried to get a roughly identical cubic regression, but instead my regression has a very strange shape.

Comment: Are you trying to fit the x,y points with a model of the form y = ax**3 + bx**2 + cx + d?  How are you actually performing the fit?  Is there a minimization somewhere?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'm using matrix multiplication to find the coefficients, but it's the same as using polyfit(x4, y, 3). There is no minimization, and I'm finding the equation for the line of regression by doing a * (x4)^3 + b * (x4)^2 + c * (x4) + d. What I don't understand is where the weird shape comes from.

Comment: It seems that the purple data are fitted to the yellow data, but probably the orientation of the array is not right. If you plot the raw points don't the purple data are fitted? I mean, try using `plt.plot(x4, y_line_x4, 'po', label='Regression Fit')`.

Comment: I tried the code you wrote but it looks identical to what I had before. Also, what does 'po' do? I received an error of "ValueError: Illegal format string "po"; two marker symbols".

Comment: You can probably replace 'po' by some other maker/color string like 'bo' (or look up of there is an abbreviation for purple).

Comment: I find the plot really hard to understand.  Can the order of the points be the issue?

Comment: There is a differente between `plt.plot(x4, y_line_x4, color='purple', label='Regression Fit')` and  `plt.plot(x4, y_line_x4, marker='o', color='purple', label='Regression Fit')`. In the first approach matplotlib automatically draw a line between the points, in the second one, every data point is drawned as a point.